# Openlayers zoom out by box selection

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have implemented zoom in by box selection using openlayers 4 , like this

```
$('#zoomin').click(function () {
        // var currentZoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom();
        //map.getView().setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
        dragBoxInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
            // condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly
        });
        map.addInteraction(dragBoxInteraction);
        dragBoxInteraction.on('boxend', function () {           
            var extent = dragBoxInteraction.getGeometry().getExtent();
            map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
            //source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function (feature) {
            //    console.log(feature);
            //});
        })

    });
```

I need to implement zoom out by box , i've searched a lot , but no luck with openlayers , by box selection i need to zoom out to the area which user selects

Comment: You can also use DragZoom for zoom in by box. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragZoom.html

Comment: but it is for zoom in , i need zoom out functionality